# Hosting laravel project error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to host my laravel project, I have uploaded the files, connected the database but when I lunch the url I get this error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I've read the other options, i updated my .env file to my new host, user and password credentials but still nothing!

Comment: Well, you should definitely double check your database configuration in /config/database.php first. If you can connect to the database with phpMyAdmin, for example, then the problem is in your config files.

Comment: As above - check /config/database.php to see what your default database connection is as well because it may be trying to use the wrong database driver even though the connection details are correctly configured.

Comment: Thanks and actually that was it. I was not referring my database correctly and there an error in the connection. My project is up and running